# SSH.Net library and use of wild card

Tags: c#, ssh, wildcard, sftp

I need to login to SFTP with SSH.NET and delete all files in the folder, but it seem like SSH.Net does not support wild card. Is it true? Is there way to fix it? Here is my code.

```
using (SftpClient sftpClient = new SftpClient(server, port, username, password))
{
    foreach (var d in sftpClient.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.Where(p => p.Key != "blowfish-cbc").ToList())
    {
        sftpClient.ConnectionInfo.Encryptions.Remove(d.Key);
    }

    sftpClient.Connect();
    sftpClient.DeleteFile("/outgoing/*.*");
    sftpClient.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: SFTP (the protocol) does not support wildcard deletions. You'll need to list the files manually and delete them one by one.

Comment: Thank you, Cory! You should have posted it as official answer, not as comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't had much luck with wildcards using this library, either.  I just ended up creating an extension method (simplistic):

```
public static IEnumerable<SftpFile> ListDirectoryWC(this SftpClient client, string pattern, Func<SftpFile,bool> includeTest=null)
{
    string directoryName = (pattern[0] == '/' ? "" : "/") + pattern.Substring(0, pattern.LastIndexOf('/'));
    string regexPattern = pattern.Substring(pattern.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)
            .Replace(".", "\\.")
            .Replace("*", ".*")
            .Replace("?", ".");
    Regex reg = new Regex('^' + regexPattern + '$');

    var results = client.ListDirectory(String.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryName) ? "/" : directoryName)
        .Where(e => reg.IsMatch(e.Name) && (includeTest == null || includeTest(e)));
    return results;
}

public static void DeleteFileWC(this SftpClient client, string pattern, Func<SftpFile,bool> includeTest=null)
{
    foreach(var file in client.ListDirectoryWC(pattern, includeTest))
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```