# sshnet removing all encryption algorithms except blowfish

Tags: algorithm, encryption, ssh, sftp, blowfish

I have an application where I use Renci.SshNet SftpClient to transmit files to a vendor's server using SFTP via SSH.
I have no problems when connecting to their production site.
However, I do have problems connecting to their Test site.

Using  Renci.SshNet SftpClient, the call never comes back after the sftp.Connect() call (it does not even times out).

I tried using other tools just to investigate the problem. I tried using WinScp and this time I got an error message trying to connect. The error was "Incoming packet was garbled on decryption". Again, no problems when trying to connect to their production site. The problem was when trying to connect to their test site.

I came across a post os somebody having the same issue, and solving it by moving in the WinScp settings the Blowfish encryption algorithm to the top https://serverfault.com/questions/548509/putty-incoming-packet-was-garbled-on-decryption . I tried that and it worked.

Then I found this posting of somebody using Renci.SshNet and, as part of his code, he removes any encryption algorithm that is not blowfish.

I tried that in my code, and then it worked.

My question is, can somebody help me understand why this approach worked.
Also, it seems this might be a known problem? why somebody else is removing all algorithms except blowfish, as part of regular code?

I also tried the same code, (removing al encryption algorithms except blowfish), in the production site, and it worked as well.

Thanks very much 
Cecilia

Comment: Your ssh/sftp server is probably configured incorrectly.

Comment: Here's the post I found in this site of somebody removing all encryption algorithms except blowfish, as a part of regular code (the problem posted there is about something else),

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308447/ssh-net-library-and-use-of-wild-card